# Pokémon had no moves left with plenty of PP

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I was playing Pokémon Y, freshly healed from a Pokémon center so I know had full PP on all my of Pokémon. I ran into a trainer battle, my leading Pokémon was Gabite, I don't remember which Pokémon the trainer used by the trainer's first move was ***Torment*** and I used the move ***Dragon Claw***.

His Pokémon was knocked out on the first hit, so he sends his second Pokémon out. Wanting to give my Gabite more experience, I left him. He got the first move again and this time used ***Encore***. So when I went to fight I get the message, "**Gabite is out of usable moves**" and then proceeded to use **Struggle**.

Is this a bug in the game to be able to use torment then encore a Pokémon like that? Or is it just a really evil way to make the other trainer's Pokémon hurt itself? Either way, I learned a new set of moves that I might run on a Pokémon.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This is a valid strategy which forces the *Pokemon* to use [struggle](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Struggle_(move)) every other turn.

As answered on [Pokemon Database Torment & Encore](http://pokemondb.net/pokebase/8354/torment-and-encore), it goes to say:

> Encore+Torment would simply make the pokemon struggle every alternate turn, because Torment says they can't use the same move twice in a row, while Encore prevents them from using a different move, so they have to use Struggle.

If you wish to use this strategy yourself, [Pokemon Database](http://pokemondb.net/pokebase/216089/what-bulky-pokemon-that-can-learn-encore-and-torment-disable) contains a list of *Pokemon* that are able to learn both **Torment/Disable** and **Encore**

***Torment & Encore***

1. Abra
2. Kadabra
3. Alakazam
4. Mr. Mime
5. Ralts
6. Kirlia
7. Gardevoir
8. Chimchar
9. Monferno
10. Infernape
11. Mime Jr.
12. Chatot
13. Gallade
14. Purrloin
15. Liepard
16. Darmanitan
17. Hawlucha

***Disable & Encore***

1. Psyduck
2. Golduck
3. Kadabra
4. Alakazam
5. Seel
6. Dewgong
7. Ralts
8. Kirlia
9. Gardevoir
10. Spinda
11. Gallade

Comment: One of my favourite tricks is to kill a Prankster by hitting it with Encore/Taunt. It can be quite effective on Shedinja too.